# Match alphanumeric characters in case statement

Tags: sh, case, hostname

I need to check in my script, whether `$1` is a valid hostname, hostname with port specified (host:port), or something else.

The firs case works fine, but the second (`([a-z0-9.-]+)`) does not

```
case $1 in
   (*:*)
   foo
    ;;
   ([a-z0-9.-]+)
   bar
    ;;
   (*)
    asdf
    ;;
esac
```

How can I only match strings consisting of `[a-z0-9.-]` in case statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plus sign doesn't have any special meaning in [pattern matching notation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13).

In this case, you need to take the opposite approach and handle invalid strings before valid ones. For example:

```
case $1 in
*[!a-z0-9.-]*)
  # handle string that contains non-*alphanumeric* characters
  ;;
*)
  # handle string that consists of all *alphanumeric* characters
  ;;
esac
```

Concerning your actual question, my naive attempt would be:

```
# exclude non-ASCII characters from a-z and 0-9
LC_ALL=C

case $1 in
*:*:*)
  # handle string that contains multiple colons
  ;;
*:*[!0-9]*)
  # handle string that contains non-digit characters after the colon
  ;;
*[!a-z0-9.-]*:*)
  # handle string that consists of an invalid hostname and a valid port
  ;;
*:*)
  # handle string that consists of a valid hostname and port
  # perform further validation of hostname and port
  ;;
*[!a-z0-9.-]*)
  # handle string that forms an invalid hostname
  ;;
*)
  # handle string that forms a valid hostname
  # perform further validation of hostname
  ;;
esac
```